# Mongo: Use field value as pipeline from-collection

Tags: mongodb, pipeline

I want to use the value of a field as the value for the from-collection of a pipeline.

```
  [
    {
        $addFields: {
            fromCollection: 'mycollection' // this would be of course a value of the object
        }
    }, 
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: '$fromCollection', // here I want to use a field reference, not a static value
            pipeline: [ ... ],
            as: 'test'
        }
    }
]
```

But this isn't working, if I use instead the value directly in the lookup: `'from': 'mycollection'` everything works as expected. Is there any way I can use the value of a field as the from-collection-name?

MongoDB Version: `db version v5.0.5`

Comment: Is it just one document?

Comment: The lookup pipeline will contain only one document, but the main aggregation will contain multiple documents.

Comment: From a quick look in the source, the function that parses the 'from' field is [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r5.0.5/src/mongo/db/pipeline/document_source_lookup.cpp#L94-L122), which appears to assume the value will be a simple string, and doesn't appear to do any expression processing.  I don't see any way to have it be different for different documents.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an approach like this is suitable:

```
var mycollectionData = db.getCollection("mycollection").findOne({...})

[
    {
        $addFields: {
            test: mycollectionData
        }
    } 
]
```

If your collection has more than one document, then `localField/foreignField` can be simulated like this:

```
var mycollectionData = db.getCollection("mycollection").find({...}).toArray()

[
    {
        $addFields: {
            test: { 
              $filter: { 
                 input: mycollectionData, 
                 as: "foreign",
                 cond: {$eq: ["$$foreign._id", "$_id"] } 
              } 
           }
        }
    } 
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I was hoping I could do all of this in one aggregation pipe, but that probably doesn't work ...